# Accessing ASP.NET local server from virtual machine

Tags: visual-studio, localhost

Don't know if maybe this question belongs on serverfault, but I'll try here first.

I'm running Visual Studio 2010 on my machine, and I want to test my ASP.NET page in IE6. IE6 is running on a virtual machine using Windows XP Mode.

The problem is that I can't access `localhost` from the virtual machine. I've also tried accessing it via my ip: `123.12.12.123:12121`, but that doesn't work either. Is there something I can setup in Visual Studio? Or is the problem most likely with the virtual pc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Cassini" web server provided as part of Visual Studio doesn't support requests from any machine other than the one it's running on. A virtual machine running *on that machine* is considered to be a different machine for these purposes.

You have <s>two</s>three options:

1. Deploy your software to IIS running on your development machine (or a.n.other machine).
2. Download [WebMatrix](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/06/introducing-webmatrix.aspx), to get hold of a copy of [IISExpress](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx), as it's somewhat easier to setup debugging against as opposed to "real" IIS.
3. Have a look at [UltiDev Cassini](http://ultidev.com/download/CassiniDownload.aspx), it's another implementation of the Visual Studio web server. I've never used it so can't comment on quality.

Comment: so is his answer 'publish it to iis'?

Comment: @gbogumil, no, there's another option, IISExpress, that I've just added to my answer =)

Comment: But isn't there some way to go around this?

Comment: If you have Windows XP professional, you can install IIS on it (from add/remove software in the configuration panel) and run your website through it. That's how I test web apps here.

Comment: @peirix, not as far as I'm aware. The web server provided with VS is designed to work [only for localhost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w566a94d.aspx).

Comment: Well, that sucks. Hmmm. Guess I'll have to look into IISExpress, then. Thanks for the tip (:

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the (test) web server that's included won't accept connections from outside. Your virtual machine has its own IP address and is seen as a different machine, just the same as any other physical computer.